# Creating a new file for my client class

Tags: java

I am very new to java and coding altogether, and I haven't figured out how to create a new file for my client class.

This is my error:

> class TestRectangle is public, should be declared in a file named TestRectangle.java

```
public class TestRectangle {
```

Here's my first class:

```
public class Rectangle1 {
```

Here's where the error occurs:

```
public class TestRectangle {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
```

Comment: I am not sure what's tripping you up. The error message seems as clear as it can be.

Comment: Right now it's saved as Rectangle1.java    I'm confused on how I need to create a new file.  Do I make a completely separate program and cut/paste the client class into the new file?

Comment: @BrettSteen put your TestRectangle in a seperate file.

Comment: @GanGnaMStYleOverFlowErroR Thanks.  If I were to just make TestRectangle private, could I leave it there?

Comment: @BrettSteen no- you cant mark classes private, check my answer below :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Java** requires that you only have one **public class** per a **file**. you have two options, either make two seperate files called **Rectangle1.java** and **TestRectangle1.java** or make your **Rectangle1** with **default access modifier** and name your **file** as **TestRectangle.java**

### Option1:

put the **Rectange1** in a seperate file (Rectangle1.java) from TestRectangle

```
public class Rectangle1
{
}
```

now, make a seperate file called (TestRectangle.java)

```
public class TestRectangle {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
```

### Option2:

Save this file as **TestRectangle.java**

```
   public class TestRectangle {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
    }

     class Rectangle1 //observe that the access modifier is default(no-modifier) 
    {
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Did you save it in a file called TestRectangle.java?
When you make a `public` class, Java requires that your file (.java) have the same name as that class.

If you'd like, you can keep your classes in the same file- just make sure that only one of them is `public`.